# REST Authentication in PHP (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, authentication, rest, codeigniter

I writing REST API form my web application. Application is written using CodeIgniter framework. Application itself is working fine, but I'm stuck on making REST Authentication. I think that basic Http Authentication will be good enough for some time. Public API is not yet planned.

Is there any code example how to achieve REST Authentication so after user is authenticated he can freely call all protected methods.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I have written up a REST Controller to make your REST applications easier to build. You can read all about it on [NetTuts: Working with RESTful services in CodeIgniter](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/).

Comment: This looks like a very comprehensive tutorial, I will read it certainly.

Comment: Just checked out Phil's tut, great stuff Phil, very informative!

Comment: You coverd security in REST_Controller! This is great, thx again!

Comment: I have used your Class and it worked perfectly.  I didn't even know this article existed.  Looks like a good read.

Comment: Hi. we are already now in authentication problem using the REST you made @PhilSturgeon. We try to login post but it seems it cant remember the session. the next request is not logged in. how can we access the session made on the login request?

Comment: REST APIs do not use sessions. You need to send the authorization in every single request. :)

Comment: @PhilSturgeon how to do that? how to generate token and send it to every request?

Answer (score 8):

If you use HTTPS, you can use Basic authentication and it's very easy to do. Just add following code to your controller,

```
   if (empty($this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_USER')))
   {
       header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
       header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
       header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
       echo 'You must login to use this service'; // User sees this if hit cancel
       die();
    }

    $username = $this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_USER');
    $password = $this->input->server('PHP_AUTH_PW');

    // Check username and password
```

I use mod_php, your auth variable names maybe different if using other SAPI modules.

Comment: So HTTP is a must, for encrypting plain user name and password in each request. Thx!