# Authentication with CodeIgniter API

Tags: web-services, api, codeigniter, rest, ssl

I have been working on a PHP project recently and I have created an API that will be consumed by mobile clients. I am using CodeIgniter as it provides a nice restful interface out of the box. I am unexperienced in PHP development and especially securing PHP web services. I was hoping to solicit some information about how I should go about implementing user authentication with my API. The information is not super sensitive but I do need clients to authenticate with the service.

Since my clients are mobile devices I'm uncertain how to go about implementing a membership provider model using CI since I won't have the luxury of a session (or do I?). Will my users merely send their credentials each time a request is made using SSL? Can someone provide me with some direction or documentation that might help?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use Phil Sturgeon's REST? http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/06/REST-implementation-for-CodeIgniter

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796950/rest-authentication-in-php-codeigniter

Comment: @Calvin No, but I did read his post here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/ Perhaps I will try his approach. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help.  Added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Phil Sturgeon's Rest API.  He's already built these things in.

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/06/REST-implementation-for-CodeIgniter